# "Find All > Related Messages" feature searches everywhere in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook 2003, when right-clicking a message and selecting `Find All` >> `Related Messages`, it would search your Inbox and Sent Items for emails with a similar subject, but it doesn't search other folders (e.g. Deleted Items).

In Outlook 2007, when using the Find All Related Messages feature, the search location (`Look for:` ... **`In:`** ...) is automatically set to the Inbox folder, the Sent Items folder **and** the whole account (the root checkbox). Unchecking the account checkbox corrects the behavior and searches only in the checked folders. Alternatively, unchecking the `Search subfolders` checkbox also solves the problem, but that too is checked by default. So basically, the fact that the Inbox and Sent Items checkboxes are checked is meaningless, since it searches the whole account anyway. I haven't been able to find a setting to change either the default search location (to remove the root account checkbox) or to remove the `Search subfolders` default checked state, so that the Deleted Items folder isn't searched by default.

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT:** Taking into account that this may be a permanent issue with Outlook 2007, as JNK mentioned, can anyone with Outlook 2010 attest whether this issue was fixed in that version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People have been complaining about this for a while.  I checked a couple of official MS websites and some unofficial Outlook user forums, and apparently it has been reported and put in as a feature request but there is no way to do it in 2007.

Comment: Could you please point me to those sources? I was unable to come up with any mention of it when I originally searched for this issue.

Comment: http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/ol2007/known_issues.htm
http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1610989&page=2
http://www.outlookforums.com/showthread.php?29359-Find-Related-Messages-in-Outlook-2007
http://www.outlookbanter.com/outlook-general-queries/89356-how-do-you-change-reset-2.html

Comment: Thanks! Any idea if it's fixed in 2010?

Answer (score 0):

How's this for a keyboard shortcut sandwich?
press and release the alt key, then type `hznfrr`

ugh. 
I right-clicked on the menu item, chose Add to Quick Access Toolbar. 
Now I just go alt then 6. 
Your number might be different.